# Get higher used bit position

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise-operators

I have some int32 value.
I need to get position of higher bit, that used to represent current value.

As example:

```
int value = 155;
```

In binary form it will be `10011011`
So higher bit used have position 8.

Is there any default or common methods for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pos` will be 0 based index

```
var pos = (int)Math.Log(155, 2);
```

Of course you should check `yourval>0`

For more tricky ones see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float

Answer (score 1):

GetBit every bit could chech true(1) or false(0) and 32 bit loop find index of first true bit.

```
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public static bool GetBit(this byte byteValue, int bitIndex)
    {
        return (byteValue & (1 << bitIndex - 1)) != 0;
    }
    public static int GetMaxBitIndex(this byte byteValue)
    {
        for (int i = 32; i > -1; i--)
        {
            if (byteValue.GetBit(i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```